# ImportError: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am learning `detectron2` from someone's code, but I got an error when I tried to import `BoxMode` from `detectron2.structures`.I think `BoxMode` got removed from the library, I want to know if they change `BoxMode` with something else that should use instead of it.

**error message:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-528200f0b892> in <module>
      6 import numpy as np
      7 import pandas as pd
----> 8 from detectron2.structures import BoxMode
      9 from tqdm import tqdm
     10 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/structures/__init__.py in <module>
      5 from .instances import Instances
      6 from .keypoints import Keypoints, heatmaps_to_keypoints
----> 7 from .masks import BitMasks, PolygonMasks, polygons_to_bitmask
      8 from .rotated_boxes import RotatedBoxes
      9 from .rotated_boxes import pairwise_iou as pairwise_iou_rotated

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/structures/masks.py in <module>
      7 import torch
      8 
----> 9 from detectron2.layers.roi_align import ROIAlign
     10 
     11 from .boxes import Boxes

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/layers/__init__.py in <module>
      1 # Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
      2 from .batch_norm import FrozenBatchNorm2d, get_norm, NaiveSyncBatchNorm
----> 3 from .deform_conv import DeformConv, ModulatedDeformConv
      4 from .mask_ops import paste_masks_in_image
      5 from .nms import batched_nms, batched_nms_rotated, nms, nms_rotated

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/layers/deform_conv.py in <module>
      9 from torchvision.ops import deform_conv2d
     10 
---> 11 from detectron2 import _C
     12 
     13 from .wrappers import _NewEmptyTensorOp

ImportError: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a dependency.  libcudart.

Comment: I solved the problem, i installed detectron2 for cuda version:11.0,  which i got error from, but when i download detectron2 for cuda version:10.2 it works fine.

Comment: cuda 11.3 worked for me